# PyPDF2 ImportError: cannot import name 'ChainMap' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, pip, importerror, pypdf

I am using `python 3.9` and installed `PyPDF2` using `pip3 install pypdf2`. When I try to import `PyPDF2`, I get the following error:

```
"File "C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\string.py", 
line 53, in <module>
from collections import ChainMap as _ChainMap
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChainMap' from partially initialized module 
'collections' (most likely due to a circular import)" 
C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What command did you use to install PyPDF2? And share some code as to how you are importing PyPDF2

Comment: I used pip3 install pypdf2. I started the code with import re and then import PyPDF2. Then I continued with a keyword search code in pdf. This is the error: ''' File "C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\string.py", line 53, in <module> from collections import ChainMap as ChainMap ImportError: cannot import name 'ChainMap' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\collections__init_.py) '''

Comment: please edit your question and put the full stacktrace into it instead of just the last part.  as it is written there is not enough information to answer this question

Comment: The stacktrace basically lists several classes imported from pypdf2. I re-installed python & pypdf2 and it works fine now. I think the python setup I used may have bad libs causing this cirvular import error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your installed pypdf2 module. Uninstall it and reinstall it using the following command

```
pip install pypdf2 --force-reinstall
```

after that if you're still getting errors make sure you import ChainMap using

```
from collections import ChainMap
```

Comment: I reinstalled it but still same. I think there may be an issue with string.py. I copied the error if it helps:
 '''  File "C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\string.py", line 53, in <module>
    from collections import ChainMap as _ChainMap
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChainMap' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\mertk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\collections\__init__.py) '''

Comment: Did you name any file in your project ChainMap?

Comment: I did not name any file as ChainMap. string.py is a python built-in module. Line 53 
``` import re as _re
from collections import ChainMap as _ChainMap```